# Convert \n in the text of a div into <br /> with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets suppose I have the following HTML file.

```
...
<div class="field">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\nconsectetuer adipiscing elit. ...
</div>
...
<div class="field">
  Phasellus faucibus molestie nisl.\nMorbi leo mi,\nnonummy 
  eget tristique non,\nrhoncus non leo. ...
</div>
...
```

The following code is supposed to replace the \n characters with HTML-like new-lines (i.e. <br /> tags). However, the result is that <br /> sequences appear in the text verbatim, i.e. as if they were escaped before being pasted into the page.

```
$(".field").each(function() 
{
    var oldText = $(this).text();
    var newText = oldText.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
    $(this).text(newText);
});
```

How do I fix it so that it breaks the latin text with real new-lines?

Comment: $(this).html(newText);

Comment: @SLaks, nice. that's likely a better approach for this scenario.

Comment: @SLaks put this into an answer I'll upvote it.

Comment: Unfortunately it turned out that pre won't break a line automatically if it's too long to fit inside. That's why I have come up with this solution.

Comment: But what if you use paths for example: \\NewCatalog\NewItem\notepad ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `.html()` instead of `.text()`:

```
$(this).html(newText);
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

Take the HTML of the "field", and then do your replace method on the html content. That way it is rendering it as needed, and not as "text". Basically, you need to render it as HTML, not text. So when you replace your new text, as HTML, it renders correctly.

Exaample:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".field").each(function() 
    {
     var oldText = $(this).text();      
     var newText = oldText.replace(/\n/g, "</br>");

     $(this).html(newText);
     });
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, this was posted while working on my solution.